# {"message": "BadGateway", "innerError": {"error": : "The server did not receive a response from an upstream server. } in Oracle Database connection

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, power-automate, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am sending request to run procedure function of oracle database from power apps.
For this, I am employing power automate flows, insert 'excuted stored procedure' trigger.

I am pulling the table datas in my powerapp via on premise gateway successfully, but I am not sure why I get this above error when I call procedure.

I mean, what is difference to pulling table vs run procedure, please help me!

Comment: Are you using "Execute stored procedure (V2)"?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I am using "Execute stored procedure" not V2, If you mean "Execute stored procedure" and "V2" are same, Yes, I am using it